# MAUI Blazor hybrid project use also for web-project?

Tags: blazor, maui

Is there a way to somehow use the views created in MAUI Blazor hybrid for a web project as well? Has anyone tried this and are there examples somewhere (I couldn't find anything so far)?

It's depressing anyway that Microsoft is always behind with ideas even now with cross-platforms. Flutter provides not only the common code base for mobile and desktop but also for web!

Thanks

Comment: I actually have a website in Blazor webAssembly and a MAUI application. Both use the same Blazor components. I just have interfaced some services to fit the website frontend environment and native application environment.

Comment: You can also refer to the official doc: [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

Officially we don't have anything for that yet. I guess you could do it with some workarounds, but I'm not sure if you should want that.

There is [this template](https://bitplatform.dev/todo-template/getting-started) from bit platform that provides you with a template that has an app, web, API project and more. I think that shares code between the two as well.

On a side-note:

> It's depressing anyway that Microsoft is always behind with ideas even now with cross-platforms.

Maybe it's a conscious choice? To be honest, and this is my personal opinion, I don't see myself ever sharing UI code between web, mobile and desktop. Even mobile and desktop is already a stretch for me, but web I think needs a special treatment altogether to not just be a stretched out version of a mobile app.

In my opinion it will still take a lot of effort to get the UI just right to make it feel like it belongs on that platform and I'm not sure if the pros outweigh the cons.

I see a lot more value in building reusable Razor components that you can share between web and .NET MAUI Blazor/Blazor Hybrid. The duplicate code should be at a minimum with that.

Comment: Thanks Gerald,
my opinion is that your statement is a paradox, because any web app or website does exactly this purpose, meaning, a UI must fit well on mobile, pad as well as desktop. So there is nothing wrong with cross-platforms just including web.

Comment: Exactly one codebase it very tempting - but it has its limitations like Gerald pointed out. The best way to achieve what you are looking to do is - segregate the entire non-UI logic is separate code base (even ViewModel functionality to some extent) and then write UI only pieces for both. That will be best of both worlds.

Comment: Yes of course, I would be very happy if that will work (see also my comment below at gonzalorf). What I can't share my opinion with Gerald about is the Microsoft justification, because Google shows us with Flutter how to shape the future.

Comment: I grew up with Microsoft (starting with MFC and then with NET from the beginning) and it's very depressing for me personally to keep experiencing the dead ends of Microsoft technologies. Why should the others always have more successful visions for the future than Microsoft? What is Microsoft doing wrong? Maybe it's because, like Gerald, they always find an excuse when something is wrong at Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

I do that by seting up a solution with the following projects:

-Maui Blazor project
-Razor Class Library project (RCL, referenced by the other projects)
-Blazor WASM project

All pages are in the RCL and can be used by the Maui and the Web projects.
The most important thing to keep in mind is that you have to modify the default Main.razor in the Maui project and add the attribute AdditionalAssemblies to add the RCL.

And the paths in the index.html (in both projects, Maui and WASM) need the prefix _content/RCL_ASSEMBLY_NAME/

Comment: I use MVVM patterns in all my projects, so my idea was to exclude the references via #if #endif and then link the Model, View and ViewModel files in both projects.

If I then change a view (or viewmodels/models), I automatically have it in both projects.

But at the moment I don't have the time to try this out because of other projects, but for now I wanted to look for possible solutions.

Comment: That's perfectly doable, and no need for #ifs. You change only the view, and is usable from both platfrms. And if you need to make platform specific actions (like get the geoposition) you can communicate to the host from the view through and object injected via DI. The view won´t know if it is in a mobile app or on a regular web browser.
Good look.

Answer (score 1):

...it's been a while, but there are still perhaps more simple solutions.

On this page you can find a suggested solution:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/sharing-code-blazor-dotnet-maui

It didn't work for me because I use Code Behind to create my projects so I have a clear separation of views and logic.

I have then also, like in the example above, created an empty project and in it I have then but only two individual projects. Once MAUI native and once Blazor Server.

I shared: Views (Forms), Code-Behind (ViewModels), static helper classes and Models.
For code-behind there was still a problem which was described here:

[Reusable razor page and code behind class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74590596/reusable-razor-page-and-code-behind-class)

pcsasa