# Reusable razor page and code behind class

Tags: razor, blazor

I have same raqor pages in two projects and I want to write this page only once in one project. In the second one I have linked the Razor page. Everything works fine as long as I don't split the code and put it in the code behind.
If I do that in the first project, then I have to specify namespace in the code behinde and here projectname is used.

```
namespace PROJECT_1.Shared
{
    public class MainLayoutBase : LayoutComponentBase
    {
    }
}
```

If I then also link the code behinde file in the second project, then the compiler tells me that it cannot find the code behinde, which is understandable because the namespace actually contains the name of the first project. If I change namespace in the linked file (code behinde) to project 2, then everything works (but project 1 doesn't work anymore because of wrong namespace):

```
namespace PROJECT_2.Shared
{
    public class MainLayoutBase : LayoutComponentBase
    {
    }
}
```

Now I don't know how to make this work. If I leave namespace out completely then it doesn't work at all because it seems Razor page finds the code behinde via namespace!

Is there any way to make the namespace dynamic at runtime because then this might work? Or does anyone have any other ideas?

Of course if I didn't use code Behinde and everything was in the Razor page (HTML + C#) then it would work, however I would rather split the code.

Thanks
pcsasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Create a CustomLayout which inherits from LayoutComponentBase.
2. Inherit your MainLayout from CustomLayout

```cs
public class CustomLayout : LayoutComponentBase
{
  // implement re-usable logic
}

namespace PROJECT_1.Shared;
public partial class MainLayout : CustomLayout
{
  // implement your logic
}

namespace PROJECT_2.Shared;
public partial class MainLayout : CustomLayout
{
  // implement your logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vikram for verifying it, because that's exactly how I implemented it in the end. I'm not quite happy because this will duplicate my number of files, but for now it looks like this is the only solution (assuming you want to separate the code from the view).